# How to make a listview to look like lined paper in android?

Tags: android, listview

i am a total noob in android app development, here is what i want

i have a listview, i am populating list  view with a custom adapter

i want to make this listview look like a lined paper even though the list is empty

(please see this [image](http://www.uiparade.com/portfolio/simple-to-do-list/) <-- i want to make the listview look like this)

i want the list view to be scroll-able, the horizontal lines should scroll with the listview

Edit:

[Figure1](http://i.imgbox.com/abbmUvEJ.png) <-- this is what i have achieved so far (using a nine-patch image)

My listview code

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000">

</ListView>
```

Comment: when did you employ us? show us some code which you started else try googling

Comment: @Nezam : i have added the code and image, please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 1 important distinction regarding your request vs. the image you linked to: the list displayed is not empty.  I point that out because your request is fairly simply achieved by assigning a background drawable 9-patch image to your list row, but filling the display with "blank paper" is going to be a bit more advanced -- achievable but try to get it working in steps.  Paper background first. :)

Comment: I used a nine-patch image just like u mentioned to get a paper background, see my edit. but i want to fill it with a lined blank paper and the paper should scroll when i scroll the listview. thanks fr ur help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use specially prepared images as background in your row layout, and then change separator color.

Comment: i want to fill the entire listview with lines even though the list is empty. i think changing the separator color wont help in this case

Comment: to create empty lines you can pass to adapter empty data or smth like this. 
You might want to extend adapter and make all stuff in there.

OR you can disable separators and pass image with bottom blue line to background. It might look like actual notepad

Comment: if i create empty lines with empty data, the empty data is clickable, but i don't need that, besides i have to calculate how many number of empty data i have to pass according to the screen size. if i set the background, the BG does not scroll, when i scroll the list view. i want the blue line to scroll along with the list view